# Overriding Methods while constructing class instances

Tags: java, android

My question pertains to the following code. When creating the instance of the `Person` class, the method `printName` is overriden.
Is this considered good practice? I ask this because this sort of syntax comes up quite often when defining event listeners in android.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class myJavaProgramme{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person newPerson = new Person(){
            @Override
            public void printName(){
                System.out.println("Method Overriden");
            }
        };
        newPerson.printName();
    }
    public static Scanner readConsole = new Scanner(System.in);
}
class Person{
    public void printName(){
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }
    private String name = "someName";
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What you are really doing there is creating an *anonymous* class, which is assignable from your `Person` type, and overriding its `printName` method. Anonymization is often used indeed in UI code - usually with `abstract` classes or interfaces though. The "best practice" all depends on the context - your minimal example doesn't provide enough context to infer anything significant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when creating the instance of the Person class the method printName of the class is Overriden

It would be more accurate to say that an instance of an anonymous subclass of Person is created (in which the method `printName()` is overridden).  You can tell the difference by invoking the `getClass()` method of the resulting object.

> Is this considered good practice I ask this because this sort of syntax comes up quite often when defining event listeners in android

It is accepted and long-established practice for certain specific kinds of situation, including in particular event listeners.  The general alternative is to define a named class and instantiate that; that's a better approach if you want to reuse the class in another context, but often that's not the case for event listeners.

In recent Java, it is possible to use a lambda instead for some situations that used to be routinely served by anonymous classes.  I suppose that most people would prefer that stylistically over an anonymous class when there is a choice between the two.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.
Overriding methods when creating instance is convenient for kind of one-time-class which rarely be reused, such as listener class for a button, ...
But for entity class like Person, its subclasses are going to be used at many places. It's better to formally extend and define subclasses.

Comment: inline implementation of interfaces and abstract methods is accepted in most cases. inline overriding of function from "normal" classes makes it difficult to understand your code.

Comment: I agree with @iamnoten. For a class like Person, an anonymous subclass will surprise your colleages. Maybe they'll waste time trying to find out why `printName()` doesn't do what they expect. If you want to override, do it in a named class that shows up in your IDE's class hierarchy view.